# How do I make a loop along with try and except to prompt user until the valid file name is given?

Tags: python

So the desired file name is data.txt. I need to use a loop that continues to prompt the user for file names until the valid file name (data.txt) is entered. My try-except has to be inside the loop.

I must test my program with the loop and a try-except to handle an incorrect name of a file name and continue to prompt the user until a valid file is entered.

For ex, if i enter 'data', the program should output:

```
Enter name of file:
File data not found.
Enter new file name:
File to be processed is: data.txt
Average weight = 164.88
Average height = 69.38
```

This is my code so far:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Complete main section of code
    # Prompt the user for the name of a file
    user_input = input('Enter name of file:\n')
    # You should complete the following loop; it will contain the try-except code
    found = False
    while not found:
        # Put your try-except code here
        try:
            my_file = open(user_input)
            lines = my_file.read()
            
        except: 
            print('File {} not found'.format(user_input))
            file_name = input('Enter new file name:')

    # Print the name of the valid file
    print("File to be processed is: ",file_name)

    # Complete the remaining main section of code to loop through the file, compute the average weight and height, etc.
    average_height = 0
    average_weight = 0
    
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
  
            sl = line.split(',')
            
            average_height += int(str(sl[0]))
            average_weight += int(str(sl[1]))
          
    print("Average weight = {:.2f}".format(average_height / 8))
    print("Average height = {:.2f}".format(average_weight / 8))
```

We are asked to make use of the

```
found = False
while not found:
```

as well as putting our try-except code in there.

my code so far only outputs:

```
Enter name of file:
File data not found.
Enter new file name:
```

And the calculations below **print("File to be processed is: ",file_name)** should be correct.

So I must ask, how do I make use of a loop with try-except in order to prompt the user until a valid file (data.txt) is entered?

Comment: The file you try to open is the one with its name in `user_input`, `open(user_input)`. But when you prompt the user to enter a different name, you store it in `file_name`, even though you never use that, with `file_name = input('Enter new file name:')`.

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't your code actually just run into an infinite loop that way?

Comment: @Grismar I get that, so should I change file_name into user_input?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? I do think the point of the exercise is to get you to think about the problem and try some stuff? (I gather this is homework)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `except` block to look like this:

```
        # Put your try-except code here
        try:
            my_file = open(user_input)
            lines = my_file.read()
            found = True

       except: 
            print('File {} not found'.format(user_input))
            user_input = input('Enter new file name:')
            continue
```

Even so, if the user will put on an existing file name that is not 'data.txt', you continue like nothing happened, which may lead to an exception (or other unwanted behaviour) in the following.
Generally speaking, you should not do such thing with try-except. Instead you supposed to compare the name to the wanted name.

In addition, things that not suppose to fail, doesn't need to be inside a try block, so it's better to put the `readlines` line outside the `try` block

And finally, it's cleaner to write your code in functions.

Comment: why did you change it to user_input ?

Comment: Because after the `continue' you jump back to the start of the while loop and there you try to open file name stored in user_input